# Read JPG files in a directory?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, os.path

I am trying to go through different image files in a directory. I am using Jupyter to run my python code as well. However I keep getting this error. Below is my code and the error I receive.

CODE:

```
import os
import os.path
for img in os.listdir('test_images'):
    if img.endswith("jpg"):
        scriptpath = os.path.dirname(img)
        print(os.path.join('test_images', img))
        # Read in the image
        image = os.path.join(scriptpath, img)
        image = mpimg.imread(image)
        # Grab the x and y size and make a copy of the image
        ysize = image.shape[0]
        xsize = image.shape[1]
        color_select = np.copy(image)
        # Define color selection criteria 
        red_threshold = 200
        green_threshold = 200
        blue_threshold = 200

        rgb_threshold = [red_threshold, green_threshold, blue_threshold]

        # Do a boolean or with the "|" character to identify
        # pixels below the thresholds
        thresholds = (image[:,:,0] < rgb_threshold[0]) \
                    | (image[:,:,1] < rgb_threshold[1]) \
                    | (image[:,:,2] < rgb_threshold[2])
        color_select[thresholds] = [red_threshold,green_threshold,blue_threshold]
        plt.imshow(color_select)
        # Display the image                 
        plt.imshow(color_select)
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

OUTPUT:

```
test_images/solidWhiteCurve.jpg
```

ERROR:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6edf7c0860b7> in <module>()
      7         # Read in the image
      8         image = os.path.join(scriptpath, img)
----> 9         image = mpimg.imread(image)
     10         # Grab the x and y size and make a copy of the image
     11         ysize = image.shape[0]

/Users/steveburgos/anaconda/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in imread(fname, format)
   1225 
   1226     if ext not in handlers:
-> 1227         im = pilread(fname)
   1228         if im is None:
   1229             raise ValueError('Only know how to handle extensions: %s; '

/Users/steveburgos/anaconda/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in pilread(fname)
   1203         except ImportError:
   1204             return None
-> 1205         with Image.open(fname) as image:
   1206             return pil_to_array(image)
   1207 

/Users/steveburgos/anaconda/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2310 
   2311     if filename:
-> 2312         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2313 
   2314     try:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'solidWhiteCurve.jpg'
```

Comment: `scriptpath` will always be an empty string because `os.listdir` returns bare filenames. Try printing `os.path.join(scriptpath, img)` (the path you are opening) instead of `os.path.join('test_images', img)`.

Comment: @unutbu You are awesome! That worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: I would suggest using [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) with a _pathname_ argument ending with `*.jpg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a path mismatch in your code, and your error is clearly showing it (file not found). When you do:

```
for img in os.listdir('test_images'):
```

You're listing the `test_images` directory in your current directory. The `img` will contain values in the form of `file1.ext`, `file2.ext` etc. as `os.listdir()` lists only the names of files and directories in it, so when you call:

```
scriptpath = os.path.dirname(img)
```

you'll essentially ges nothing because the `img` doesn't contain any path information. So, finally, when you do:

```
image = os.path.join(scriptpath, img)
```

You technically pass only the file name as `scriptpath` is empty. Since your image is in the `test_images` subdirectory and not in your working directory, you'll normally get file not found.

There are a several ways to solve this issue, the easiest would be to just declare a lookup directory in a variable and use it when needed, e.g.:

```
target_path = "test_images"
# ...
for img in os.listdir(target_path):
# ...
    image = os.path.join(target_path, img)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use glob like grillo opinion, or you can use the following lambda statement

```
files = os.listdir(file_dir)
img_files = list(filter(lambda x: '.jpg' in x, files))
```

Comment: Please explain what this code does and how it does it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion I prefer using the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) library to return a list of files in a directory. 

`import glob
print (glob.glob("/home/peter/pictures/*.png")`

returns:

`['/home/peter/pictures/pic1.png', '/home/peter/pictures/pic2.png', '/home/peter/pictures/pic3.png', ...ect]`

If you want to continue with your approach, I am sure that you are not giving a correct path to the folder directory. 
Think about it, how does the program know where `test_images` is located.